# Failed to open eclipse for first time

Tags: java, eclipse, failed-installation

Hello I want to run eclipse for the first time, when I click on eclipse exe file, the warning occur "Java run time environment or java development kit must be available in order to run eclipse, No java virtual machine is found in the eclipse path"

so I define java global variables and add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin" to PATH variable but also this warning occur
"Failed to load JNI shared library C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\bin..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
* 64-bit OS
* 64-bit Java
* 64-bit Eclipse
```

or

```
* 32-bit OS
* 32-bit Java
* 32-bit Eclipse
```

Comment: actually the OS doesn't matter. I'm using win7 64bit with a 32bit java/eclipse combination (for stability reasons). but java and eclipse have to match.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://java.com/en/download/installed.jsp and use the directions given to install a standard Java runtime.

After that, Eclipse should start.

Answer (score 0):

It wont work by setting the "PATH" variable.   You need to also set "JAVA_HOME" variable pointing to your JDK install, which is the directory that contains "bin" (I usually don't point to a JRE but I think it will work if you did).

Installing a new JDK will do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest jre version and add its bin address (EX:-`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;.;`) to *classpath variable* in *environment variables*. Save it and try to open eclipse which is installed before, it should open now